# How better send data from BroadcastReceiver to Activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I wan catch SMS in my app and show it o my view. I create BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
            }
            StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                bodyText.append(message.getMessageBody());
            }
            String body = bodyText.toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, body, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

And it show Toast wuth SMS body. Now i dont know what should I do

1. Create Service and pass SMS to service. And get SMS from service
2. Use Otto observer and send data(SMS) from:
         1.  BroadcastReceiver
         2.  Service
   and catch in my activity.
3. Another more correct way

And if I will use Otto (I want it) where better  send data - from BroadcastReceiver or pass data to service and send otto message from Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otto or EventBus is for me the most simple solution and the solution that will reflect best your `Activity` lifecycle.

A great start is to `register`/`unregister` your bus from `onPause()` and `onResume` like so :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
}
```

Next, post an event from your `BroadcastReceiver` like  `BusProvider.getInstance().post(new SmsEvent());`

Your fragment or Activity will received the event via the @Subscribe method and the `SmsEvent` parameter type of the method.

It seems you don't need any Service here except if you want to save the data when the activity is not open.

Comment: I use Otto every day, and i know how it work. I ask "if I will use Otto (I want it) where better send data - from BroadcastReceiver or pass data to service and send otto message from Service?" because i use it for another

Comment: Depends of your logic. If you manage your sms from a Service, you better send the event from the service. If it not make sense, send from the BroadcastReceiver